# where to download vagrant boxes

Tags: vagrant

I know http://www.vagrantbox.es/ provide many vagrant boxes for us to use, but I found many of their url download address is out of date. vagrantcloud.com or https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search is alternative to me. But when I run `vagrant up ubuntu/trusty64 --provider virtualbox` I got this:

```
sean@apptest:~$ vagrant up ubuntu/trusty64 --provider virtualbox
A Vagrant environment or target machine is required to run this
command. Run `vagrant init` to create a new Vagrant environment. Or,
get an ID of a target machine from `vagrant global-status` to run
this command on. A final option is to change to a directory with a
Vagrantfile and to try again.

sean@apptest:~$ vagrant global-status
id       name   provider state  directory                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active Vagrant environments on this computer! Or,
you haven't destroyed and recreated Vagrant environments that were
started with an older version of Vagrant.

sean@apptest:~$ vagrant init
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

sean@apptest:~$ vagrant up ubuntu/trusty64 --provider virtualbox
The machine with the name 'ubuntu/trusty64' was not found configured for
this Vagrant environment.
```

It seems that I can't vagrant up a box from online download. But I do not find download address from https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64 too. Is there a better way to get these boxes?

And what if I want to download https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead v0.2.3 ?

Thanks~

Comment: Try upgrading to a newer version of vagrant

Comment: $ vagrant version
    Installed Version: 1.7.1

Need I upgrade to the latest version is 1.7.2 ?

Comment: That should be high enough. Try `vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64; vagrant up --provider virtualbox`.

Comment: Yeah, it worked! Now I can see the download url https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/14.04/providers/virtualbox.box .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @jordanm , the question is solved.
In a clean directory(without Vagrantfile):

`vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64`

Then run `vagrant up --provider virtualbox`. This will lead to search box from https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search/boxes .

Or just run `vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64`.

If you wanna download box file, you can see complete url address where box locate